# Add minutes from one column to datetime column in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a column in my database named Created which is a datetime and a column named Minutes which is a varchar(5) and will contains values such as 0, 60, 120, etc.

How can I write a LINQ statment that only returns those records:

where Created + Minutes has gone passed the current time?

Thank you!

--- Update: code so far ---

```
var results = from emails in MyDAL.Context.Emails
   emails.Created.Value.AddMinutes(double.Parse(emails.Minutes)) > DateTime.Now
   select emails;
```

Comment: Is there a reason Minutes is varchar rather than int? If it was int it would save a cast / convert.

Comment: It was an int but was changed.  It's a long story :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others looking for the answer, here is how I ended up making it work....

```
System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(emails.Created, emails.Minutes) < DateTime.Now
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could *try*:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

var query = from record in db.Records
            where record.Create.AddMinutes(int.Parse(record.Minutes)) > now
            select record;
```

Whether that will work or not depends on the LINQ provider...

Comment: Here is what I get, "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMinutes(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."